# Leak between copper and braided supply line

Tags: plumbing

Today I found a slow leak in my kitchen faucet. It’s a pull-down style faucet with small copper tubing going through the counter, and the leak is where that copper meets the braided supply line. I don’t see any way to put a wrench on the copper pipe, so how can I fix this? I’m not sure, but it seems like maybe this fitting is meant to be permanent from the factory?

I don’t know the brand of faucet. The stem is a square, and I took photos of some identifying marks. If anyone can identify this, that would be helpful if I need to order a part.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those flex hoses made to be tighten/loosen with hex fitting.  Seems like bad design with brass pipe, unless it lifts up to see nut.  Think flex nut threads into brass.

Comment: To me that fitting looks like it seals using 1 or 2 O-rings - in which case attempting to tighten it more will not achieve anything. Try unscrewing it completely and check that the O-ring(s) are still in good condition.

Comment: Additional note: if those are O-ring seals then they don't need to be much more than finger-tight.

Comment: You’re right, there are 2 o rings in there and they look good

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I'm used to always holding the backside steady with a second wrench when tightening anything, so I was afraid to try this here.  But after reading @brhans comments, I tried it, simply holding the brass sleeve with vice grips and tightening the connector a quarter turn and that did the trick.  I suppose the reason this piece doesn't have wrench flats is it's designed to be just finger tight, but in this case it required a little extra.  This connector has two rubber O-rings inside, so the threads do not make the seal.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and thanks for posting your solution. Please also give yourself a check-mark click so others know this has an answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a quick connect:

Something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAwXhxOeBqk

Try pulling back on the brass sleeve.

Comment: No the brass sleeve doesn’t move. I figure it out, I just grabbed the brass sleeve with vice grips and tightened. I’m not used to this kind of connection not having wrench flats

Comment: @ElliottB if you've resolved your problem, please write up what you did in an answer of your own (self-answer are _more_ than acceptable), then click the check mark as soon as the system will let you. This will help others in the future who have a similar problem.